# Adding key-values in yaml at specific location using python or sed

Tags: python, sed, helm3

I am trying to add following key values in values.yaml at exactly at particular location, sed doesn't help much, as it breaks indentation of yaml. Is there any other way to get this right.

Ex:
sample yaml

[image]

desired yaml

[image]

Comment: Please replace all images with its text. See:  [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` you can insert a block of text before `livenessProbe` this way:

```
sed -e '/livenessProbe/i\
volumes:\n- name: my-agent\n  persistentVolume:\n  claimName: my-agent
' sample.yaml
```

If `sample.yaml` is

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 2Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 512Mi
livenessProbe:
  httpGetPath: /heartbeat
```

the result would be:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 2Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 512Mi
volumes:
- name: my-agent
  persistentVolume:
  claimName: my-agent
livenessProbe:
  httpGetPath: /heartbeat
```

If the code block to add is in a yaml file `addons.yaml`:

```
sed -e "/livenessProbe/i\
$(cat addons.yaml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g')
" sample.yaml
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark icon @Learner